# why there is an "を" in 「運転免許は持っているけれど、車を全然運転しない人たちのことをそう呼ぶんです」

Tags: grammar, particle-を

[image]

I assume that そう here is the そう used for not direct quoting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This を is merely a direct object marker, indicating the object of the verb 呼ぶ.

`AをBと呼ぶ` means "to call A B".

> 車を全然運転しない人達のことをペーパードライバーと呼ぶ。
>   (They) call people who don't drive at all *paper drivers*.

In this case, the adverbial phrase ペーパードライバーと is replaced by そう, which is like "so", "that way" or "like that" in English.

> 車を全然運転しない人達のことを**そう**呼ぶ。
>   (They) call people who don't drive at all like that.

Comment: It is also helpful to note that 呼ぶ is sometimes translated as `to designate; to name; to brand`  See: http://jisho.org/word/%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B6

Comment: is it really the object marker of 呼ぶ or is it of 運転しない? EDIT: nevermind. there's two を in the sentence. I somehow overlooked the other one!

Comment: @psosuna Oh, I somehow overlooked the first を... I should've mentioned it.

Comment: 2 を's are ok, but not 3, right ? :)